# nativescript-angular/application cannot find module

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

am developing an app using nativescript and angular2 with angular2seed advanced. while developing this app face a problem ie,while giving 
import {nativeScriptBootstrap} from "nativescriptangular/application";
Cannot find module 'nativescript-angular/application'.am new to this how can i solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

package.json

```
"nativescript-angular": "0.6.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

Your nativescript-angular package version is a bit old - a lot of things has been deprecated and a number of breaking changes were introduced in the latest versions of Angular-2 so you should use the latest nativescript-angular version (currently 1.1.2) which is up to date with the latest versions of Angular-2 as well.

With the new versions the bootstrapping of NativeScript app is done with these imports:

```
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic, NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/platform";\

...
platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppComponentModule);
```

For example take a look at [this sample application](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng) or the [advanced-seed nativescript app](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced/blob/master/nativescript/package.json)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I gave

Comment: I gave platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(NativeModule, [
    provide(WindowService, { useClass: WindowNative })
   ]); then shows an error cannot find module provide. what should i do?